# Moving a 2D object along circular arc between two points

Tags: unity, 2d, mathematics, vector

I have a sprite which I need to move along a curve between two points in 2D space. Speed must be consistent all the way. No physics involved. How can I achieve this? [image]

The object is sun sprite.

[image]

Comment: Why a parabola, rather than an ellipse or circular arc?

Comment: The equation of a parabola can't be found with two points only. (Infinite numbers of solutions : [How is the equation of a parabola found with two points?](https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-equation-of-a-parabola-found-with-two-points)). You need at least 3 points. Check this link: [How to find the equation for a parabola for which you are given two points and the vertex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049239/how-to-find-the-equation-for-a-parabola-for-which-you-are-given-two-points-and-t)

Comment: Circular arc will do fine. I am not very good at math.

Comment: I would simply pick a point that's equal distance from sunrise and sunset then rotate the sun around it..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Bezier Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Given 2 given points, you have to define one third point yourself that controls where the curve is made. In your example you can create the point between your two given points, plus some height.

```
// Assuming point[0] and point[2] are your starting point and destination
// and all points are Vector3
point[1] = point[0] +(point[2] -point[0])/2 +Vector3.up *5.0f; // Play with 5.0 to change the curve
```

Then to compute the curve in a script for an object to travel to it, do this:

```
float count = 0.0f;

void Update() {
    if (count < 1.0f) {
        count += 1.0f *Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 m1 = Vector3.Lerp( point[0], point[1], count );
        Vector3 m2 = Vector3.Lerp( point[1], point[2], count );
        myObject.position = Vector3.Lerp(m1, m2, count);
    }
}
```

Basically, to compute a Quadratic Bezier Curve (one with three points) you have to find the interpolated points of it's two lines, construct a line with those two points (The green line in the gif), and interpolate again to find a final point.

[image]

As you can see, if you increase the Y value on your second point, the curve will be bigger.

Edit:

If you want to create moving objects like a sun and a moon, create 3 `Vector3` points: starting point (where the sun begins travelling) an ending point (where the sun ends up) and a control point (that controls the curve). The control point should be located above the mountains, but the exact value depends on what kind of curve you are looking for.

Now substitute these points with the above example:

```
point[0] = startingPoint;
point[1] = controlPoint;
point[2] = endingPoint;
```

I assume that once the sun (or moon) reaches the ending point, they can just disappear from the scene, and re-appear on the next day on the starting point, so it's location until then is irrelevant.

Comment: What if I have two objects for moving. Like sun and moon. And I want them to take turns. What is it with counting then?

Comment: @NikitaDemidenko I edited my answer with a sun and moon example

Comment: It is moving to fast. Just instantly sprite is at the finish point no mater  how I tweak count value.

Comment: @NikitaDemidenko Can you post some code? I'm afraid there is nothing I can do, since this method I posted work, unless I see what you did wrong in the code.

Comment: I have created more elaborated question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157646/unity-unable-to-control-speed-of-the-movement 

I accept your answer here cause I think it is valid, it is just I do something wrong.

Comment: @NikitaDemidenko You didn't have to create a new question, if speed was your only problem I could provide the solution here. But you mentioned something about the sun not animating at all and being initalized on the end point.

Answer (score 4):

Myself, I'd use a circular arc for this - that way it's easy to get consistent speed.

```
IEnumerator FollowArc(
        Transform mover,
        Vector2 start,
        Vector2 end,
        float radius, // Set this to negative if you want to flip the arc.
        float duration) {

    Vector2 difference = end - start;
    float span = difference.magnitude;

    // Override the radius if it's too small to bridge the points.
    float absRadius = Mathf.Abs(radius);
    if(span > 2f * absRadius)
        radius = absRadius = span/2f;

    Vector2 perpendicular = new Vector2(difference.y, -difference.x)/span;
    perpendicular *= Mathf.Sign(radius) * Mathf.Sqrt(radius*radius - span*span/4f);

    Vector2 center = start + difference/2f + perpendicular;

    Vector2 toStart = start - center;
    float startAngle = Mathf.Atan2(toStart.y, toStart.x);

    Vector2 toEnd = end - center;
    float endAngle = Mathf.Atan2(toEnd.y, toEnd.x);

    // Choose the smaller of two angles separating the start & end
    float travel = (endAngle - startAngle + 5f * Mathf.PI) % (2f * Mathf.PI) - Mathf.PI;

    float progress = 0f;
    do {
        float angle = startAngle + progress * travel;
        mover.position = center + new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle)) * absRadius;
        progress += Time.deltaTime/duration;
        yield return null;
    } while (progresss < 1f);

    mover.position = end;
}
```

Now you can start the object moving with:

```
StartCoroutine(FollowArc(sunSprite, sunrisePoint, sunsetPoint, radius, daylightDuration));
```

Comment: Seems to be a good solution for speed consistency. But does it provide trajectory adjustment? I mean is it only perfectly round or is it adjustable to stretch arcs height but preserve start and finish points coordinates?  Sorry if it is obvious in the code. I need a day or two to digest it :)

Comment: This particular version is perfectly round, though you can shape how steep or shallow an arc you want by varying the radius parameter (bigger radii = shallower, straighter arc)

Comment: @DMGregory please take a look at this for me https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157685/how-to-animate-an-arc-from-the-middle-in-both-directions

Comment: Can you explain why you multiple the perp by a trig function plus the square root? I don't understand that.

Comment: @WDUK I'm seeing this late, but this is just Pythagorean theorem: \$a^2 + b^2 = c^2\$ implies that \$b^2 = c^2 - a^2\$, which in turn gives us \$b = \pm \sqrt{c^2 - a^2}\$. `Mathf.Sign()` is not a trig function (note the "g" - even if it's pronounced the same as "sine"/`Mathf.Sin()`, it's a different function) - it returns +1 or -1 depending on the sign of the argument, giving us the \$\pm\$ part of the formula above.