# How to animate an arc from the middle in both directions

Tags: unity

I have been able to make an arc that animates from one end to another using the following coroutine:

```
 IEnumerator AnimateArc(float duration)
{
    float waitDur = duration / pts;

    for (int i = 0; i <= pts; i++)
    {

        float x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        float y = center.y + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        arcLineRend.positionCount = i + 1;

        arcLineRend.SetPosition(i, new Vector2(x, y));

        ang += (float)totalAngle / pts;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitDur);

    }
}
```

How can I animate this arc from the middle in both directions

1. at a constant speed
2. with an ease (animates slightly faster in the middle and slows down towards the end)

Comment: Could you provide a short .gif so that we can see what your current implementation is doing? I may have a solution (look up using AnimationCurve to change speed in coroutine), but I am unsure as to what you want to do exactly.